# How To Write C# Code To Return Counts Of Users In Database Table For Dashboard Display

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
public static MemberCountsModel UCount { get; private set; }

public static MemberCountsModel GetMemberCount()
{
    dbFactorySetup.InitializeDBSettings();
    DbConnection SQLConn;
    var dbPF = dbFactorySetup.GetDbProviderFactory();

    try
    {                             
        using (SQLConn = dbPF.CreateConnection())
        {
            SQLConn.ConnectionString = dbFactorySetup._conn;
            SQLConn.Open();
            using (DbCommand SQLCmd = SQLConn.CreateCommand())
            {                       
                DateTime DefaultDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                SQLCmd.CommandText = dbFactory.TransformSQL(SQL.GetMemberCount, dbFactorySetup._dbType);
                long UCount = 0;

                 UCount = (long)SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }

        return UCount;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;

    }
}
```

I am trying to count the numbers of members in a database table using the above code. Though it returns a 204 StatusCode, but no value is returned. What have I not done right?
NB: SQL = GetMemberCount = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users / SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users . Any of the SQL statement was used.

Comment: `long UCount = 0;` creates *another* variable with the same name as your static field.

Comment: Never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You will lose your stack trace. Just do throw; instead. However, seeing as you don't actually do anything with the exception you catch here, you might as well just simplify this by removing the entire try/catch from the code.

Comment: HTTP Status 204 (No Content) indicates that the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no content to send in the response payload body. I would suggest debugging your code and copying the query that you generate from the code. Try to run that query in your DB and see what result it produces. If it is not giving any data then you could revise your query. After you get the correct result from the query, try to do the necessary changes in your code. After that try to run your code to see whether you get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by on primary key in order to count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY primarykey`
```